# Referencing error

Tags: java, eclipse

Got error while running project from Eclipse IDE:

```
'Launching MyProjec' has encoutered a problem.

The archive /myPro/lib/activation.jar which is referenced by the classpath not exist.
```

How to know who is referencing `activation.jar`?

Comment: Which projects do you have in your workspace and are referenced by MyProjec?

Comment: I have only one project in workspace - MyProjec

Comment: Check your project's `Java Build Path` property page.